# ASP -response-flush-flushes-partial-data

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a web app with an ASP server side and I use an iframe for data push.

An ASP handler flushes every once in a while some javascript to the iframe:

```
context.Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>top.update('lala');</script>");
context.Response.Flush();
```

My problem is that sometimes, when I receive the data, I don't get the full text. For example I will receive this : update('lala');

One workaround I have is to have a thread flushing '..........' every 500ms. (Then I will receive script>...... which will complete my javascript.)

However I am sure there must be a way to have Response.Flush() sending the whole chunk of data. Does someone have an idea on how to use properly Response.Flush() ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently after tons of google searches, I found the answer. The IIS server was compressing the output with GZIP, then it will seem to ignore all Response.Flush calls.
This is turned on by default in IIS7 and on Windows 7. If you disable it, it works fine.